# AWS Autoscaling instances in pending state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have tried with multiple ASG configs within my VPC with all combinations of LC for my webserver image. However each time the instance spawns, it gets stuck in Pending state.

Can anyone point me what am I doing wrong or some direction that I should look into?

[(More Detailed)](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=781654&#781654)

Thanks

Comment: In the Auto Scaling Group, what details are listed in the **Scaling History** tab if you expand the line(s)? If you launch an instance with that AMI, but outside of Auto Scaling, does the instance launch successfully?

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein... for around 30-60min the status stays in "Not yet in Service" and when it changes to cancelled expanding it shows "Launching a new EC2 instance: i-06b31a57fb7b2e9d8. Status Reason: Only EC2-Classic instances may be linked."... Based on this I recently tried another approach, where, in LC I did not link it to vpc and ASG worked. But can't get my head around why so.(updated on the forum as well)

Comment: Does your ASG have the correct subnets in which It can launch instances.The VPC Security groups on the LC are to be configured when using ClassicLink connection (Probably your instances are being launched in a subnet that is not adhering to the LC security group for classic link)

Comment: Is your environment Classic, VPC or a mix of both? These days, you really should have everything in VPC. It's possible your VPC is configured for Classic but instances are launching in VPC, or something equally confusing.

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, I do have correct subnets for ASG. But how to check for your approach to know if I am doing it wrong...

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Interesting... I do have a VPC environment configured and all my infrastructure is within VPC. On checking it up, I saw I have ClassicLink enabled but no ClassicLink DNS support.
I think that both of you and Rajesh are pointing to the same thing but it's not very clear to me. Can either of you elaborate it? Thanks again for helping me out, meanwhile, I'll also dig in to understand this.

Comment: If you have all of your instance inside the VPC then you do not need to setup security groups on the LC. Configuring security groups and subnet on ASG will suffice and everything should work smoothly.